# Хранение большого количества фотографий Java

Tags: java, spring

Пишу web-сервис на java+spring.
Суть в том, что около 10 человек будут каждый день загружать фотографии и писать название коробки.
Например, Коробка 220 и загружать 50 фотографий.
В день выходит около 10000 фотографий и 200 коробок (1 фото - 100КБ) и также нужно чтобы при выборе коробки, отобразились все фотографии коробки.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше всего хранить эти фотографии, какие вообще способы есть. За год выйдет большое количество фотографий. Читал что то про Amazon s3

Answer (score 1):

Есть два варианта как решить задачу:

1. Хранить фотографии в бд в base64
2. Хранить файлы на диске и в бд сохранять их расположение

Файлы предпочтительнее хранить на диске.

Answer (score 1):

Можно посмотреть в сторону MinIO, есть интеграция с spring.
В бд можно хранить связь коробка к картинкам(название). По названию картинки получать из MinIO нужный массив байтов и передавать пользователю.